# What is the complexity of this program. Is it O(n)?

Tags: time-complexity

This is a simple program I want to know the complexity of this program. I assume this is O(n) as it has only a single operation in one for loop.

```
a = int(input("Enter a:"))
b = int(input("Enter b:"))
sol = a
for i in range(a,b):
    sol = sol & i+1

print("\nSol",sol)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you define `n := b - a`. The complexity is actually `n log(n)`. There is only 1 operation in the loop so the complexity is `n * Time(operation in loop)`, but as `i` consists of `log(n)` bits, the complexity is `O(n log(n))`

EDIT:

I now regard `n := b`. It does not affect my original answer, and it makes more sense as it's the size of the input. (It doesn't make sense to say that `n=1` for some big `a,a+1`)

To make it more efficient, notice you calculate `(a)&(a+1)&(a+2)&..&(b)`.
So we just need to set `0`'s instead of `1`'s in the binary representation of `b`, in every place in which there is a `0` in this position for some `a <= k < b`. How can we know whether to set a digit to `0` or not then?  I'll leave it 
to you :)
It is possible to do in `log(n)` time, the size of the binary representation of `b`.
So in this case we get that the time is `O(log(n)^2) = o(n)`

Comment: How can I implement this in O(n) then?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is O(n), sort of. You have to remember O(n) means the number of operations grows with the size of the input. Perhaps you're worried about the & and (i+1) operations in the for loop. What you need to keep in mind here is these operations are constant since they're all performing on a 32-bit integer. Therefore, the only parameters changing how long the program will run is the actual number of iterations of the for loop.

If you're assuming n = b - a, then this program is O(n). In fact, if you break down the actual runtime:

per loop: 1 AND operation, 1 addition operation
now do (b-a) iterations, so 2 operations per loop, (b-a) times = 2*(b-a)
If we assume n = b-a, then this runtime becomes 2*n, which is O(n).

Comment: Well explained. Thank you.

Comment: If `n` is a 32-bit integer, then `n < 2^32`, hence `n` is constant. So by that logic the runtime is `O(1)`